The bot does not send notifications at certain times
The bot does not create a reminder, although it should. he just doesn't see time. I want it to just work, in 24 hour format.
# Reminder
notes = {}

@bot.command()
async def note(ctx, time_str: str, *, message):
    try:
        time = datetime.strptime(time_str, "%y.%m.%d %H:%M")
        now = datetime.now()
        if time <= now:
            await ctx.send("You have selected a past time. Please choose a future time.")
            return
        notes[time] = {"author": ctx.author, "message": message}
        await ctx.send(f"Note saved for {time.strftime('%y.%m.%d %H:%M')}")
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send("Invalid time format. Use the format 'yy.mm.dd HH:MM'.")

async def check_notes(): 
    await bot.wait_until_ready()
    while not bot.is_closed():
        now = datetime.now()
        for time, note in list(notes.items()):
            if time <= now:
                author = note["author"]
                message = note["message"]
                embed = discord.Embed(
                    title="Reminder!",
                    description=f"{author.mention}, here's your reminder:\n{message}",
                    color=discord.Color.blue()
                )
                embed.set_thumbnail(url=author.avatar_url)
                await ctx.send(embed=embed)
                del notes[time]  # Remove the note after sending the reminder
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

@bot.command()
async def my_notes(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed()
    embed.set_author(name=" | Your Notes", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar.url)
    if not notes:
        embed.description = ":calendar: You don't have any notes yet."
    else:
        note_list = "\n".join([f"• **{time.strftime('%y.%m.%d %H:%M')}**: {note['message']}" for time, note in notes.items() if note['author'] == ctx.author])
        embed.description = f":calendar: | Your Notes:\n{note_list}"
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)

I tried everything in my power, and nothing helps. I sit all day and don’t understand anything.

From the code you have sent, it doesn't look like you're actually calling check_notes anywhere.
A function with an while not Bot.is_closed() is not recommended for this. Instead, use tasks, which is available in the namespace discord.ext.tasks. And this is a very bad way to create reminders, because if the bot crashes or you restart it, all the reminders will be lost. I recommend using a database to store the reminders. This is an example for a reminder command.

Tasks: https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/

